# chart.js v2 - how to 'fill' the graph when using time scale

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im creating a chart with [chart.js v2](http://www.chartjs.org/) and I have a good working graph which uses a [time scaled axis](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale). Now I want to show whole hours in the axis so I set the option like this:

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
        unit: 'hour',
        unitStepSize: 1,
        displayFormats: { 'hour': 'H:mm' }
    }
}]
```

This works good but I have gaps at the beginning and end of the graph.
[image]

How can I make it fit like this:
[image]

**Codepen:**
http://codepen.io/WilbertE/pen/wzRmWr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `min` & `max` attributes of the `time` property :

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: "time",
            time: {
                min: /* Set your min here .. */,
                max: /* .. and your max here*/
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Which should be the first an the last of my data?

Comment: Depends on what you have in your data. If you know what you are getting (raw values), just add the lowest value as the `min` and the highest as the `max`. Or maybe you don't know what you're getting (*from a query for instance*) ?

Comment: It doens't work. I've made a codepen: http://codepen.io/WilbertE/pen/wzRmWr

Comment: My bad. I placed it in xAxes: [{}] instead of xAxes: [{ time:{min:,max:}}]