# Chart.js MySQL PHP time scale

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, chart.js

I would like to draw a graph using `RPi`, `MySQLi`, `PHP` and [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/). To do that I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2F5iTlPgaV8&t=138s):

For now,  my graph is empty. *X* axis is 'undefined' and *Y* axis has got a wrong range.
In my case *X* axis should show time format *values(HH:MM:SS)*. Does anybody know how to properly set received time data from MySQL for Chart.js?

I also checked this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179935/chart-js-v2-how-to-fill-the-graph-when-using-time-scale) but it did not work for me:

Thank you!

---

### index.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "airqualitysensor";
$password = "password";
$database = "temperatura";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM temperaturaodczyt";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$data = array();
foreach($result as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
    }
$result->close();
$conn->close();

print json_encode($data);
?>
```

---

### app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost/index.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        var tczas = [];
        var temperatura = [];

        for (var i in data){

            tczas.push(data[i].tczas);
            temperatura.push(data[i].temperatura);

            }


        var chartdata = {
            labels: tczas,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label : "Zmierzona temperatura",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(200, 200, 200, 0.75)",
                    borderColor: "rgb(200, 200, 200, 0.75)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgb(200, 200, 200, 1)",
                    hoverBorderColor: "rgb(200, 200, 200, 0.75)",
                    data: temperatura
                }
                ]
            };

        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var lineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "line",
            data: chartdata
            });


        },
    error: function(data) {

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Please try to be as specific as possible about what is not working.

Comment: Maybe you're not parsing json properly, so try add `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data)` at start of success function.

Comment: (1) Since it looks like `index.php` doesn't need any input from `app.js`, it might be worthwhile to run that program in isolation and "see" what exactly the JSON data looks like (you might even paste some of it here later). (2) Take a standalone sample of a `chart.js` example of your choice and create a static data set manually (maybe based on the fields you want to show) for the graph to be plotted. (3) With that, you'd know whether the `X` and `Y` axes of your data are exactly like how `chart.js` expects them to be, or whether the results would need modifying / transposing a little bit.

Comment: DrKey - that helped, thank you a lot :)